# Nested loop assignment to struct member

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc

I'd like to have an array of instances of `TestStruct` with a single member of type `int`. I'd like the output to be

`1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6`

but it is `0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0`

I'm a little stumped, because I don't really get how this isn't working:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int num;
} TestStruct;

int main(void) {
    int i, j;
    TestStruct *test = malloc(sizeof(TestStruct) * 18);

    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            test[i].num = i;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
        printf("%d ", test[i].num);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I just call `printf()` inside a nested for-loop, it works fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i, j;

    for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            printf("%d ", i);
        }
    }
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Hint: What does `test[i]` do?

Comment: Your printing loop that "works fine"  has the indices swapped if you compare it to the desired output.

Comment: @MOehm Fixed. I did a lot of edits and compiling, and apparently I got them swapped. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to write it like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            test[i*3+j].num = i+1;
        }
  }
```

Comment: That makes sense. Accepted answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Change you code to this, You should be indexing **i** element not **j**

```
 for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            test[j + (3*i)].num = i;
        }
  }
```

The above code will print
111111222222333333

In order to achieve 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6 your code should look like below

```
for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                test[j + (3*i)].num = i;
            }
 }
```

**Update**: You need to keep track of outer loop or index you are appending number to so it does not rewrite everytime outer loop is run. I did it like this **test[i + (3*i)]**

Comment: This will initialise six instead of three elements. You need a combination of indices or a third, independent index.

Comment: Nabik, 2nd one has same problem again. you only write from element 1..6 in array. Result will be 012345600000000000

Comment: LOL, code still has problem. result will be 'segmentation fault'. :D

Comment: @Nakib I'll have to fiddle with it for a bit tomorrow. I accepted Afshin's post as answer, but thank you too!

Comment: Nakib, please take some care when posting your answers. Ideally, test them before posting them. You update repeatedly, but the updates aren't much better. For example, `j + (3*i)` will have values of 18 through 20 in the last iteration of the outer loop. These indices are out of bounds.

Comment: @Nakib reason for segmentation fault is that you go out of array boundary.

Comment: @Afshin  thanks and M oehm will keep in mind for next time